# Magento Homepage Ajax cart text "MY CART" need change to "My Basket"

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, magento

In Magento Website, I want to change the homeapge ajax "MY CART" text to "My Basket".
I have tried much but no success. I want to change by code or database. 
I tried trough translate.csv, forntend inline translator and much more.

I need help to solve this issue.

Comment: What ajax cart module are you using ? you need to show part of template

Comment: why not translation csv? if you need to change directly, you need to find which template file is calling this.

Answer (score 0):

Usually via the frontend inline-translator it should work.
be sure to refresh the language cache!

If this is an extension you should be able to find translation files in app>locale>yourlanguage and search for "my cart"

Again, be sure to empty the language cache!